# Initializing struct with union of arrays

Tags: c, struct, union

I noticed there have been many posts about this subject but I cannot seem to pin point anything that would help.

I have defined the following code:

```
typedef struct
{
    float re;
    float im;
} MyComplex;

typedef struct
{
    float rf;
    union
    {
        float     noise[4];
        MyComplex iq[4];
    };
} RfTable_t;

RfTable_t Noise[2] = 
{
    { 1.2f, .noise=0.f },
    { 2.1f, .noise=0.f };
};

**EDIT - Add function Test**

void Test()
{
    Noise[0].rf = 2.1f;
    Noise[0].noise[0] = 3.2f;
}
```

I am trying to define the **global** variable `Noise` statically.
I get the following error:

```
   expected primary expression before '{' token
   expected primary expression before '{' token
   expected primary expression before '}' before '{' token
   expected primary expression before '}' before '{' token
   expected primary expression before ',' or ';' before '{' token
   expected declaration before '}' token
```

Comment: The semicolon in `{ 2.1f, .noise=0.f };` should be a comma (or should be removed).

Comment: Change the semicolon in `{ 2.1f, .noise=0.f };` to a comma or delete it. If the problem continues to occur, then provide a [mre] and state which compiler you are using and with what switches. The code currently shown in the question does not produce the error messages shown with GCC or Clang.

Comment: `<complex>` is C++, not C. The question is tagged wrong, and that may explain why the error messages do not match for people compiling in C.

Comment: Good point.  I'll make another adjustment.

Comment: This is making less sense. How can you choose to change `<complex>` to a structure of your own definition? What was the **actual** code you were using that exhibited the problem? Are you compiling as C or C++? Are the error messages shown in the question the **exact** error messages you get from GCC? If so, how come they are missing the line and column numbers that GCC prints with its error messages? Paste **exact** text, stop making changes that obscure information.

Comment: Which version of GCC? What command-line switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the smallest changes I could to make it compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    float re;
    float im;
} MyComplex;

typedef struct
{
    float rf;
    union
    {
        float     noise[4];
        MyComplex iq[4];
    };
} RfTable_t;

RfTable_t Noise[2] = 
{
    { 1.2f, .noise={0.f} },  // Initialize NOISE with {0.f} instead of 0.f.
    { 2.1f, .noise={0.f} }   // Remove extra semi-colon.
};


int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

### Clean Compile:

https://ideone.com/pvI9Ci

**In brief:**
`noise` is an array.
To initialize it you must use the array initializer syntax:
`{ value, value, value }`

You did not have brackets around your value of `0.f`.

Also, you had an extra semi-colon.

Comment: No *"odd reason"* about it.  When you follow the rules, it works.  It is simple.

Comment: The program compiles on ideone.com without the braces around the `0.f`. it compiles in GCC without those braces. It compiles in Clang without those braces. Removing them was unnecessary, it did not cause the error messages shown (it would cause “missing braces” messages, if enabled), and it is, unfortunately, not the correct answer to the problem in spite of OP’s acceptance. The actual cause must be some other issue, but the question fails to present the required information.

Answer (score 2):

Any structure, union, and/or array to be initialized needs its own set of curly braces to initialize it.  Specifically, the union needs a set of braces, and the `float` array inside the union also needs braces:

```
RfTable_t Noise[2] =
{
    { 1.2f, { .noise={0.f} } },
    { 2.1f, { .noise={0.f} } }
};
```

Note also that you had a stray `;` inside of the initializer.

Comment: The C standard does not require braces for those.

Comment: I've defined `Noise` as you have shown up above but I am still getting those same errors. I have double checked my code against what I have posted and I did post the correct data structure.

Comment: @jiveturkey Create a piece of code with *only* what is needed to reproduce the problem, then post that *exact* code you compiled.  Also, specify which compiler you're using and the exact command used to compile.

Comment: I edited my question above to reflect a workable product.  I am using GCC.

Comment: @jiveturkey If I compile the exact code you posted minus the "EDIT" line, I do not get the errors you describe.  Also, the header you use suggests this is C++.  Compiling with g++ also does not give the errors you show but does give others.  Your error messages should match the posted code.